# How to choose proper if statements in linked list?

Tags: java, if-statement, linked-list, conditional-statements

What is the difference between these if statements?

1. `if (current.next!=null)`
2. `if (current!=null)`

Comment: first statement checks if you have next element or not, second statement checks if current element is null!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following Linked List:

```
HEAD ---> ["value2" | -]--> ["value3" | -]--> ["last_value" | null]
```

Assuming `current` points to "value3":

```
HEAD ---> ["value2" | -]--> ["value3" | -]--> ["last_value" | null]
                                 ↑
```

then `current.next != null` is `true`, since `current.next` is actually the "next" node.

Now let's assume `current` moved to "last_value", now we'll have:

```
HEAD ---> ["value2" | -]--> ["value3" | -]--> ["last_value" | null]
                                                    ↑
```

Now `current != null` is `true` whereas `current.next` is `null` (which is an indication that there's no more nodes).

So "Choosing proper" if statement is not a good question since it really depends on what you want to check, they're two different validations.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are iterating  the list and you want to know when you're at the end of the linked list.
If you have the following:

```
if (current.next!=null){
    current = next
}
```

then it doesn't matter. they are both fine. considering that `current` will never be `null`.